What Load Generator Configurations to run load test
The controller is installed on one machine and the Load generator is installed on another machine, what setup do I need to do in the load generator machine to run the Load Test?
Means, I need to install the Load Generator agent and then need to do specific settings. Can you brief me whole process?
I know how to configure LG in the controller through IP address or Hostname. But want to know what configuration I need to do in the Load generator machine where its physical or cloud based

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
